# Deck Of Cards - 12 Card Hands

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Problem: Find the number of twelve-card hands containing four cards in each of three suits.

My solution:

1. pick a suit : 4 ways.
2. choose 4 cards from the 13 in that suit: ${^{13}}{C}_{4}$ ways.
3. pick another suit: 3 ways.
4. choose 4 cards from the 13 in the new suit: ${^{13}}{C}_{4}$ ways.
5. pick the final suit: 2 ways.
6. choose 4 cards from the 13 in the final suit: ${^{13}}{C}_{4}$ ways.

Hence, total number of ways is $4\cdot{^{13}}{C}_{4}\cdot3\cdot{^{13}}{C}_{4}\cdot2\cdot{^{13}}{C}_{4} = {^{4}}{P}_{3}\cdot\left({^{13}}{C}_{4}\right)^3 $ total hands.

This is the incorrect answer. Why?

Comment: What is the point of suit picking?  All you want is to choose $4$ spades, $4$ hearts, and so on...so $\binom {13}4^4$.

Comment: @lulu Not entirely. We only want three suits.

Comment: @Arthur  Ah!  Too early in the morning.  $4\times 4$ is not $12$.  Thanks!

Comment: So, you need to choose the omitted suit.  That is one factor of $4$.  But that's it.  the others are then determined.  You are overcounting in that you count $\spadesuit, \heartsuit, \diamondsuit$ and  $\heartsuit, \spadesuit, \diamondsuit$ as separate cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the incorrect answer because you overcount. If you pick the suits of spades, clubs and then hearts, your method counts that as different form picking first hearts, then spades, then clubs, even though they result in the same hands.

Actually, you count each hand exactly six times, once for each order of the three chosen suits, so you should get the correct answer by just dividing by $6$. If you want the correct answer from the start, you could begin by picking three suits, which may be done in $^4C_3$ ways. Then you pick four cards from the first suit, four cards from the second suit, and four cards from the third suit. In other words, your $P$ should've been a $C$.

Comment: This makes sense. I was trying to compare it to a problem I saw earlier in which the number of cards from each suit picked is different. In that case, spades, clubs, hearts would be different to hearts, clubs, spades. So permutations would need to be used. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you (after shuffling it) can tell from looking at the hand which suit was picked first, second and last, then that matters, and if not, then it doesn't. As a final example, if you wanted your hand to consist of 6 cards  from one suit and 3 from each of two other suits, then it would be $(^4P_1) (^3C_2)$, or, equivalently, $(^4C_2)(^2P_1)$, multiplied by $(^{13}C_6)(^{13}C_3)^2$.